# App crash on creating NSdictionary for Json in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

i am working on in app purchase app in which i want to verify purchase transaction receipt with my developer server along with other information like Device VendorID, software version , device name and product id wish to buy.

I am using NSDictionary to create Json but it crash when i try to add

```
 NSMutableArray *MainOBJ = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:IDdict,deviceData,kMyFeatureIdentifier,jsonObjectString,nil];
```

in which IDdict is device id string , deviceData is dictionary which content device information like name , software version and kMyFeatureIdentifier is product id NSstring wish to buy. and jsonObjectString is encoded transaction receipt string.

here is my code

```
- (void)verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
 
 //TODO
 // currently working on JSON to send to server .
   NSLog(@"In verifyReceipt method");

   jsonObjectString = [self encode:(uint8_t*)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length];
 // jsonObjectString=@"TESTING";

NSLog(@"Json Object encoded receipt is %@",jsonObjectString);

NSString *IDdict = [[NSString alloc ]initWithString:[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString]; // Device UDID

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"NULL",[[UIDevice currentDevice] model],[[UIDevice currentDevice] name],nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"serial",@"constructor",@"name",nil];
NSDictionary *deviceData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];  // Device information like name , device model , serial number

NSLog(@"Json question dict created");


//TODO: **It crash here**

NSMutableArray *MainOBJ = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:IDdict,deviceData,kMyFeatureIdentifier,jsonObjectString,nil]; // purchased Item ID of previous item
NSMutableArray *MainKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"device",@"video","@receiptData", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *MainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:MainOBJ forKeys:MainKeys]; // final string of data

NSLog(@"Json Main dict created");


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:MainDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Purchase product Json string:\n%@", resultAsString);


ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://xyz/dev.php/video/verifyReceipt"]];
[request setPostValue:resultAsString forKey:@"verify"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
request.showAccurateProgress = YES;
```

i got  "NSLog(@"Json question dict created");" in my log after it crashes.
and my expected json format is like this

```
        {
      "ID" : "E6E95901-006B-4569-8D2B-FA29A0307F80",
     "device" : {
     "name" : "iPad Simulator",
     "constructor" : "iPad Simulator",
     "serial" : "NULL"
       },
     "video" : "com.amm.happyclip.4445Video",
     "receiptData":"DSKLFKSGERPOKFLJGMZEKLEMSERLKEMZTRKGDGFLefklezkgem"
       }
```

Screenshot of error
[image: screenshot of error]

Any suggestion , help appreciated Thank you

Encoding method which return string and i just assign that string to "jsonObjectString"

```
- (NSString *)encode:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length {

static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *)data.mutableBytes;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSInteger value = 0;
    for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
        value <<= 8;
        
        if (j < length) {
            value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
        }
    }
    
    NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[index + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[index + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
       
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: What. Is. The. Error. Message!!?

Comment: Those capitalized variable names are extremely unreadable.

Comment: @borrrden i just got this on log 
(lldb)

Comment: That looks like a breakpoint.  Did you put a breakpoint on that line?  Maybe you could put a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: @borrrden No i didnt use any breakpoint and i added screenshot. if i remove my jsonObjectString variable from dictionary than it work perfect..

Comment: For future reference, you have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (don't ever just say that though, it requires more debugging).  You should enable exception breakpoints if you want to narrow it down more.  However it seems like you found the line causing the problem.

Comment: What *is* jsonObjectString?  What are you doing to it in `encode:`?  Are you just trying to make it into an `NSString`?

Comment: @borrrden jsonObjectString content return string from encode method.it return the encoded transaction string which need to verify purchase transaction

Comment: Verify that it is functioning correctly.  Check the return value!

Comment: @borrrden return value is encoded transaction and if i print in log i can see encoded string and i print all objects in MainOBJ array and they are perfect no Null or Nil value

Comment: problem is that i can't add two string so i create one Nsdictionary name is "deviceDataDictioanry" without receiptData and i create another dictionary with "receiptData " and "deviceDataDictionary" and create final json by using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each object in MainOBJ is nil and if you create dictionary with nil object it crashes your app, or they are already released.

try to log objects from MainOBJ array.

Comment: i log objects from mainOBJ and all are printing perfectly No one having null value